# How do I take a screenshot of a single view object instead of the entire screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, screenshot

So I have a UIImageView with some text overlayed on the top and bottom. I want to get a screenshot so I have a new image with the text overlayed on it. This is the code I was working with but I am unable to take a screenshot of the my UIImageView object properly.

```
func generateImage() -> UIImage
{
    // Render view to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.imageView.frame,
        afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let memeImage: UIImage =
    UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return memeImage
}
```

Alternatively, I have also tried the code below, though the image saved is the right size/area of the screen, it ends up with blurry version of what I took a screenshot of:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

imageView.layer.renderInContext(context!) // tried drawInContext but it didn't work at all
let memeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return memeImage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions will allow you to adjust the scale factor to suit your screen size.  Second, passing in the view you want to capture will ensure that you are working with the correct view/subviews.

```
func generateImage(currentView: UIView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(currentView.frame.size, true, 0.0)
        currentView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let memeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(memeImage, nil, nil, nil)

        return memeImage
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is similar to the alternate method I tried. Unfortunately I run into the problem of having only the image copied, but not the text I overlay on the image. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Any subviews will be included.  Is it possible that your text is not a subview of the view you are trying to capture?

Comment: Can we include subviews to UIImageView via storyboard? It hasn't let me. One potential solution could be to include the UIImageView and UITextLabels inside a UIView, and run the function on the UIView.

I'm assuming programmatically adding UITextFields to the UIImageView would also require constraints to be programmatically added - something I'm willing to learn if it solves the issue.

Comment: You've got it.  As long as everything is part of the same UIView it will work.

Comment: Upvoted as the perfect solution for what I needed. Taking a shot of the whole screen was messing it up, and @squarehippo10 the comment about being a SUB VIEW and not just behind or in front of the other views was key.